# Error: Cannot find module 'styled-jsx/style'

Tags: next.js, next.js13

While trying to upgrade Next.js from 12.3.4 to 13.5.5.

It happens in the api's handlers ( /pages/api folder )

```
import { createRouter } from "next-connect";
import cors from "cors";

const router = createRouter();
router
.use( cors( {
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        callback( null, true )
    },
    credentials : true,
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "HEAD"],
} ))
.get( async(req, res) => {
  const resp = await getData(req);
  return res.json(resp);
})

export default router.handler({
  onError(err, req, res) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: (err).message,
    });
  },
})

async function getData(req) {
  return { data : "hello" }
}
```

It happens also in versions:

- 13.5.5-canary.8
- 13.5.4
- 13.5.3
- 13.0.0

Only happens in production, it works fine in dev mode. I'm hosting this build in netlify and using the pluggin @netlify/plugin-nextjs, it works fine with version 4.37.4 ( next 12.3.4 ) and already tried 4.38.0, 4.38.1, 4.40.2 without luck.

What I tried?

- Installing different plugin versions
- Installing different nextjs versions
- Deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling everything again
- npm i -S styled-jsx

Thanks in advance